# Central Limit theorem solving for n with absolute value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

First off, I'd like to apologize for the lack of latex in this question. I'm not understanding a crucial step in a homework problem I have. It states:

- Suppose that a measurement has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2 = 25$. Let $X$ be the average of $n$ such independent measurements. How large should $n$ be so that $P(|X − \mu| < 1) = .95$?

I've worked on it extensively and got stuck. I found a couple of solutions online which determined that $n=96$. I obviously understand that using the CLT is critical, therefore you get, from the above inequality:

$.95 = P(|X − \mu|/(\sigma/\sqrt{n}) < 1/(\sigma/\sqrt{n}))$, simplifying to:

$$.95 = P(|Z| < 1/(5/\sqrt{n}))$$

Somehow, the solution jumps from that last bolded step to:

$$.95 = P(|Z| < 1.96)$$

I have a feeling that this somehow involves a Z-table but for the life of me, I can't understand how these two steps are connected. Past this step, I completely understand the steps to solve: you just set $1.96 = 1/(5/\sqrt{n}))$ and get $n=96.04$, essentially $96$.

What am I missing here? And is there a way to do it *without* a Z-table?

Thanks so much for the help! Cheers!

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of a $Z$ table? If you do, please write down the precise meaning of the numbers you see in your $Z$ table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a reasonable start on this, so let me try to nudge you over the finish line. First, a restatement of the problem to make sure the lack of TeX notation did not lead to confusion. You are going to sample at random enough observations $n$ from a normal distribution with unknown population mean $\mu$ and known population variance $\sigma^2 = 25$ (population standard deviation $\sigma = 5$), so that
$P\{|\bar X -\mu| < 1\} = .95,$ where $\bar X$ is the sample mean of your $n$ observations.

We  express your key event $A$ in a form that contains a standard normal random
variable $Z$ as follows

$$A = \{|\bar X - \mu| < 1\} = \{-1 < \bar X - \mu < 1\} = 
\{\sqrt{n}/\sigma < \frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} = Z < \sqrt{n}/\sigma\}.$$
Now, in order for $P(A) = .95$, you need  $\sqrt{n}/\sigma = \sqrt{n}/5 = 1.96.$
I see you have found that $n = 96.04.$ (Some people might want this "rounded up" to $n = 97$ just to make sure the original inequality holds (with a bit of room to spare.)

**Addendum:** Problem seems to have been edited. If you will look for 1.96 in the margin of a normal table, you will find the corresponding value in the body of the table is .9750 (or maybe .4750 depending on the style of the table).
This indicates there is 1-.9750 = .0250 = 2.5% (or .5 - .4750 = .0250) in the right
tail of the standard normal distribution beyond 1.96. By symmetry, there is
another 2.5% area below - 1.96. That leaves 95% of the area between -1.96 and 1.96, or $P\{|Z| < 1.96\} = .95$. The Empirical Rule says there is about 95% of the area under a "mound shaped" (nearly normal) curve between $\pm$ 2 (close to 1.96). In R software 'pnorm(-1.96)' returns 0.02499790 (essentially 2.5%). There is no
way other than 'numerical integration' (intensive computation) to find areas under the normal curve. (Standard methods of calculus don't work.)

Comment: Not sure how to interpret "what am I missing." In case there's something else, write a specific comment, and I'll be watching my feedback file on this site.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Right now, what I'm still unclear on is how why this is true (from your post): **"Now, in order for P(A)=.95, you need √n/σ=√n/5=1.96."** I feel like there's something incredibly simple that I'm missing here, because it seems like a decently trivial step. Thanks!

Comment: Look at the last member of the displayed equation. What quantity there has a standard normal distribution? Also, $P\{|Z| < 1.96\} = P\{-1.96 < Z < 1.96\}$. (Think about it. If you need more, ask. If not, please click to 'Accept' the answer so this will no longer be on the list of questions without satisfactory answers.)

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I understand the breaking of the absolute value as you've written above. My thought process was this: you want the probability to be 95%, leaving 2.5% on each of the tails of the standard normal dist. I then look at Z-table and find the 1-.0250 = .9750, which obviously corresponds to our 1.96. Is that correct? It seems a little time-consuming to hunt down a number in the 300 cells of a Z-table, is there another way to tackle this that I'm just completely missing? Sorry for dragging this out, I really do appreciate the help!

Comment: Yes, correct. Numbers in the body of a normal table are in order, so when you get used to it, it's not as bad as looking up a word in the dictionary. [Also, probably soon to come, you will see that the bottom row of the table of Student's t distribution (perhaps marked 'df = $\infty$') refers to the standard normal distribution, and  1.96 is easy to find there. Finally, you may soon learn how to use software to find such numbers. But one thing at a time.]

Comment: Awesome thank you SO much for the help! Much appreciated!

Comment: Why is it {$\sqrt n / \sigma < Z < \sigma / \sqrt n$} and not {$-\sqrt n / \sigma < Z < \sqrt n / \sigma$} ?

Comment: Thanks for the note. Fixed a couple of typos.